# postInstantiate buildSessionFactory slow/memory huge database

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Having an ERP database with more than 520 tables, the postInstanciate of EntityPersister is very slow and its consuming more than 512M which is to much for only one session Factory, the application become very slow.

Comment: Thank you, but some hibernate core modification bring build session factory from 60 secondes to 5 (without any bug), but still to do better, and memory pb is no more posed

Comment: As far as I know, you are allow to **reuse** your SessionFactory. So you should only have to wait once per start of your application. This might by annoying if you are writing a standalone application, but should be less relevant, if you are writing a server-backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't post all changes, but here the ideas :

1_ Hibernate creates many Entiy Loaders for all entities and collections (many type of loader for each entity and each collection),
this operation should be done on demande, entity or collection loader should be created when its needed, not during the build of session factory, even if you have 500 entities it doesn't mean that the user will load data from each entity.

```
    private Map LoaderMap = new LoaderMap();//instead Hashmap  
    class LoaderMap extends HashMap{
        @Override
        public Object get(Object key) {         
            Object obj = super.get(key);
        ….
        }
    }
```

2_ `DirectPropertyAccessor` is calling getDeclaredField twice once for the buildGetter Method and the second for buildSetter, using a cache is a good optimization

**Response to Ulrich Scholz**:
I add a jar containing all fixed Classes to the project, in my case its Webapp application deployed on Tomcat, all you need is to fix the loading order of the Jars using :

```
<Context>
<Resources>
      <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResourceSet"
                base="${catalina.base}/webapps/AGIWERP/WEB-INF/lib/AAACLZ-1.0.jar"
                webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib/AAACLZ-1.0.jar" />
</Resources>

</Context>
```

This mean your classes should be loaded before the original ones

Comment: Could you give some more hints on how to replace the default EntityPersister classes with the one holding your suggested changes (postInstantiate). Do I need to change the hibernate code itself or can I supply my replacements to the library? We are using Hibernate 3.5.2